# Maximize floating point precision in ASCII with a fixed field width

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write some floating point data to a scientific file format that specifies ASCII fields of a fixed width (in this case, 16 characters). I'd like to maximize the precision written to the file, but every number written **must** fit in the fixed field limit.

Simply calling `std::setprecision(12)`, for example, results in a loss of precision for `M_PI` and field overflow for `M_PI / 10000`, even when combined with `std::setw(16)`. Similar arguments can be made against `std::fixed`

The best I've been able to come up with is

```
constexpr int fieldWidth = 16;
string formatField( double value ) {
  stringstream ss;
  ss << setprecision(fieldWidth-7) << setw(fieldWidth) << scientific << value;
  return ss.str();
}
```

The assumption here is that no number is greater than `1e100` or too close to zero (ex `1e-100`). It is also less than optimal for positive numbers less than 100 since it cedes a character to the `+` sign and two more to the exponent.

Can I improve on my current solution? Improvements would include 1) Better precision across a range of numbers and/or 2) A stronger guarantee that the field width won't be violated. Solutions using boost are welcome as well.

Comment: Are you aware that a `double` can only guarantee 15 digits (integer+decimals), independently of the exponent?

Comment: @Ripi2 Yes, I am. However, as in my example, I can only capture 10 digits (fieldWidth-7, plus the number in front of the decimal), and I'm finding for my application that those additional 4-5 digits would be very useful.

Comment: Maybe you could use *fixed point* math and hexadecimal notation.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I appreciate the suggestion. Unfortunately, I only control what the file writer does. The file readers expect to read numbers in 16-character ASCII chunks.